# Aggregate/sum with dimension in row and colum

Tags: r, sum, aggregate

I know the standard aggregate function, example code

```
aggregate(hp~cyl/vs, data=mtcars, FUN="sum", na.rm=TRUE)
```

that returns:

```
  cyl vs   hp
1   4  0   91
2   6  0  395
3   8  0 2929
4   4  1  818
5   6  1  461
```

However i would like to put the "vs" in the columns, like this:

```
      vs   0    1
  cyl     hp   hp
1   4     91   818
2   6    395   461
3   8   2929
```

How can this be done in R?

Comment: I don't understand the label `hp` in your expected output. The `vs` levels are `0` and `1`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` answer:

```
mt = as.data.table(mtcars)
dcast.data.table(mt, cyl ~ vs, value.var="hp", fun.agg = sum)

#    cyl    0   1
# 1:   4   91 818
# 2:   6  395 461
# 3:   8 2929   0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `xtabs`

```
xtabs(hp~cyl+vs, res)
  #      vs
#cyl    0    1
#  4   91  818
#  6  395  461
#  8 2929    0


res <- aggregate(hp~cyl/vs, data=mtcars, FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xtabs()` directly on the `mtcars` data, without using `aggregate()` as an intermediate step:

```
xtabs(hp ~ cyl + vs, data = mtcars)
```